# celery worker dead but broker connection alive

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, celery, messagebroker

I have been working on an application whose infrastructure is something like below-

We are using AWS for deployment.

1 EC2 instance - my broker(rabbitmq server) is running here

celery workers run on Auto Scaling Group(ASG) instances.

Problem - worker creates a connection with the broker. Once a worker is done with its responsibility, the ASG instance(worker instance) dies but in EC2 instance the rabbitmq connection remain there in "running" status. These connections then pile up to 900+ and then it stops accepting new rabbitmq connection.

I did little bit search and found that each connection takes about 2-3MB and once the rabbitmq's ulimit is reached it doesn't accept new connections. Didn't get much details from celery doc.

How can I make sure from celery worker that before dying it is closing the broker connection?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know much about celery- but is it creating the RMQ connection as a separate logical process, with its own lifetime?

Comment: Yes. It is creating a TCP connection.